# Not getting response from Deutsche Bahn API using PHP/Curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using Deutsche Bahn Api to get train records in Europe but the API is returning an error:

> The document has moved https://www.bahn.de/p/view/home/kontakt/error500.shtml.
>        I do not know german so I am stuck and confused.
>        Here is the code i tried. Can you state what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
 $t=time();
 $sig = md5('d06c00525957425b5719bba2c7a2c5a6'.$t);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <AngebotssucheRequest xmlns="http://www.bahn.de/webservices/dritte/angebotssuche/request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:db="http://www.bahn.de/webservices/dritte/datatypes/db">
 <Header us="prabal" l="EN"  t='.$t.' sig='.$sig.'/>
 <RequestData d="8079732" s="8079706">
 <DateTimeH d="822312689">
 </DateTimeH>
 </RequestData>
 </AngebotssucheRequest>');


 $header = array(
     "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
     "Accept: text/xml",
     "Cache-Control: no-cache",
     "Pragma: no-cache",
     "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
     "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
 );

 $soap_do = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fahrkartendritte.bahn.de/webservices/fahrkarten/v1" );
   curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
   curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
   curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml);
   curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);

 if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
  $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
  curl_close($soap_do);
  print $err;
   } else {
     $response = curl_exec($soap_do); 

    curl_close($soap_do);
    $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);
        print_r($response);
       print 'Operation completed without any errors';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: All of the DB APIs listed at https://developer.deutschebahn.com/store/apis/list appear to have `api.deutschebahn.com` endpoints. Are you sure you're using recent documentation?

Comment: I should also note your XML isn't valid, you're not quoting your t or sig attributes in your Header element.

Comment: Yes I am using recent one and I am trying to get data for start point station to end point station. d represent start location id and s destination,I have created sid as they told me but I dont know where I went wrong

Comment: @zack6849 i am passing xml in header.

Comment: @PrabalThakur Can you link to the API documentation?

Comment: @ceejayoz can you share your mail id because I was not able to find one on internet let me mail you the pdf

Comment: No, don't do that. Link to the API docs or upload it somewhere, so everyone here can see it.

Comment: @ceejayoz here it is the docs for api https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t7n7C3Yspe3sE0FNiAWVACdYfE2B9oIu

Comment: You need to publicly share that url, as of now we need to request permission

Comment: Yes I have done that please see now

Comment: @PrabalThakur This documentation says the API is from 2010 - that's nearly a **decade** old. I'd bet this API has been deprecated (for new apps) in favor of one of the ones at https://developer.deutschebahn.com/store/apis/list and that's why you're getting the "this has moved" notice.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the information I know this but there no new documentation for this , you were able to find new documentation for this I was not able to find the link for the new documentation.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is the link for url http://www.bahn.de/webservices/dritte/angebotsdetails/request but now there is no response